# Does C include built-in sockets?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm planning out a science project, and I'm doing some research about sockets in various languages. Strangely enough, I cannot find whether C has sockets as part of some internal resource, or if the language requires an external library to use sockets. From what I've seen, I'm inclined to think that it is part of an internal resource, but I want to be sure.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sockets are specified by POSIX but not C by itself. Basically any modern operating system you're likely to encounter *except Windows* is approximately POSIX-conformant. On Windows, the `WINSOCK` library provides a very poor substitute for standard POSIX sockets.

Comment: Don't give them breathing room!

Comment: Great, Of course, I have Windows. perhaps I should use linux for my testing.

Comment: If you use Windows but want to develop in a more universal POSIX-like environment, Cygwin may be a good choice. It attempts to emulate POSIX on Windows and does a pretty damn good job.

Comment: I've heard of Cygwin, would it slow programs executed in it?

Comment: @Curlystraw: not so as you'd notice. Its programs are real Windows binaries, but linked against the cygwin libraries, which present the more-or-less POSIX APIs. It's not an emulator. I'm sure that if you looked, you could find something that's slower in the cygwin library implementation than the equivalent Windows functions, but there's no general overhead.

Comment: Perhaps the best advantage of Cygwin over mingw/msvc these days is that UTF-8 actually works. You don't have to fool around with ugly Windows-specific `WCHAR`/`TCHAR` APIs; just use the standard library functions with UTF-8 strings and everything just plain works.

Comment: A possible disadvantage of Cygwin, which I present for consideration and not because I think it's a killer argument against, is that it can be a bit out of date. For example, a few years ago it carried a critical security flaw in its `gpg` package for about a year after it had been fixed upstream. It's usually more annoying than harmful, though - most apps, if you need the latest and greatest you can grab the Windows distribution instead, or (if you're feeling brave) build the source under Cygwin. And if you're just doing a bit of socket programming, you don't need the latest anything.

Answer (score 2):

No, C is lightweight and doesn't include sockets. But the compiler suite or your OS may have included a socket lib. Most likely you'll need to reference socket.h, netinet/in.h, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[`#include <sys/socket.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the C language itself does not define any input or output, and depends on an external library (std) even for console input/output.  See WINSOCK for sockets on windows through C.

Comment: C99 defines some file IO as part of its standard library (Appendix B.18), but sockets are not part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are a part of the libc or of the OS API, so they are not part of the language proper.